# Fitting a star light with a 3D Gaussian

Tags: c#, curve-fitting, gaussian

I've got a star image, let's say 15 x 15 pixels.
The star light can be modeled as a 3D Gaussian, which exactly is what I'm trying to do.

The function I'm using is f(x, y) = A·exp(-[(x-xc)^2/2σ^2+(y-yc)^2/2σ^2]) where:

- xc, yc the coordinates of the estimated star centroid
- A the pixel value at (xc, yc)

The algorithm I've implemented is the Levenberg-Marquardt.

I got stuck at the following point, in the L-M algorithm - at each iteration - I need to compute a vector with the differences between my sample and f(x, y).

If I compute the Gaussian f(x, y) using the pixel positions (row, column) as (x, y) of  course it will be everywhere 0, except around xc and yc. Which is not correct.

I was thinking to make a normalization letting x and y vary just between 0 and 1 (of course normalizing xc and yc as well).

Could it be a good approach?

Thanks.
Cheers

Comment: "The star light can be modeled as a 3D Gaussian" - really? What are you trying to achieve? Also, try to use a larger value for sigma, e.g. half of the image width/height

Comment: My goal is to find out the best fit for the star light for computing its FWHM (which is sigma * 2.355) with sub pixel precision,

Comment: I don't see any programming coding question here, more a Math / Physics modeling question. My opinion is that your question is off-topic. Maybe check in other related Stack Exchange sites ?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example graphical 3D surface fitter using the scipy implementation of Levenverg-Marquardt in curve_fit(), this example should be easily adapted to your needs.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels


def func(data, a, b, c):
    X = data[0]
    Y = data[1]
    return a*X + b*Y + c


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```